# Execute a Script When XCode Runs My App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iOS application that relies on a web server to keep track of information like players and games. Is there some way I can have XCode restart the server every time I start the app in the simulator? I am using Django so starting the server involves one terminal command.

Comment: Strictly speaking the answer is no - there is no documented hook for running scripts once a debugging session starts - oops, no, now I remember, there is something in Xcode4... lemme check. There is however a hook for running scripts once a build process is invoked, as explained by Gabriele in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to you target settings and add a Build Phase.
You can set an arbitrary script that runs at every build.

Here's an example taken from one of my projects:

[image]

Simply click on the *Add Build Phase* icon on the bottom right and select *Add Run Script*.
As you can easily find out by yourself, you can specify the shell to run the script into, as well as other handy options.

In your specific case a simple oneliner

```
python manage.py runserver
```

would probably do the trick

Comment: Would this work since runserver normally runs in the foreground?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues. I'm not 100% sure, but I guess the server log will be visible in the log navigator.

Comment: Of course you may think of more sophisticated solutions such as open an executable script and use the XCode script just as a trigger. Example `cd "${SRCROOT}"; 
./runmyserver.sh`.